# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop while nested list iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `React` code:

```js
export default function Technologies({ technologies }) {

  return (
    <>
      { Object.keys(technologies).map((key, i) => (
        <span>

          <span className={styles.post}><h3 className={'bold300'}>{key}</h3></span>

          <div className={styles.techList}>
            <ul key={i}>
              { Object.keys(technologies[key]).map((key2, idx) => (
                <li key={idx}>{key2}
                  { technologies[key][key2].map(key3 => (
                    <span key={key3.name} className={styles.badge}><Image src={key3.name} width={key3.w} height={key3.h} /></span>
                  )) }
                </li>
              )) }
            </ul>
          </div>

        </span>
      )) }
    </>
  )
}
```

Here you can see nested iteration, and everywhere I use `i` or `idx` to create unique key for list, but still keep getting warning for this string:

```js
...
<ul key={i}>
...
```

As I said, I know what this error means, and even know how to fix, but not in this case, I just don't know, where I should put `key` to prevent this warning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` should be present on the root element. So, the first `key` should be on the `span` and *not* on the `ul`.

```
export default function Technologies({ technologies }) {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(technologies).map((key, i) => (
        <span key={i}>
          <span className={styles.post}>
            <h3 className={"bold300"}>{key}</h3>
          </span>
          <div className={styles.techList}>
            <ul>
              {Object.keys(technologies[key]).map((key2, idx) => (
                <li key={idx}>
                  {key2}
                  {technologies[key][key2].map((key3) => (
                    <span key={key3.name} className={styles.badge}>
                      <Image src={key3.name} width={key3.w} height={key3.h} />
                    </span>
                  ))}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </span>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```